# How do I disable this grid?

Tags: age-of-wonders-3

My cat walked across my keyboard, I've no idea what buttons he hit, but this grid overlay has appeared and I haven't been able to get rid of it!

[image]

Does anyone know the shortcut to remove it? AOW3 doesn't come with a manual and I can't find one online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the top right corner of the screen, there are three buttons. The middle one is **Map Settings**. Click that, and the very top checkbox should read **Hex Grid**. Uncheck that.

[image]

Comment: Cheers man, much appreciated!